# MySQL : Multiple counts in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products. Every product has a company and a worker of that company that produces it.

Something like this:

```
product | company | worker
--------------------------
1          2        John
2          2        Mike
3          2        Jim
4          3        Mark
5          3        Fred
6          2        John
etc...
```

Is it possible to run one query by company, and count all products by specific worker that works for selected company.

**For example:**

```
SELECT (count how many products each employed worker made) WHERE company = 2;
```

**RESULT :**

```
John:2
Mike:1
Jim:1
```

**EDIT : What i tried so far:**

I tried grouping by worker.

```
SELECT product FROM products WHERE company=2 GROUP BY worker;
```

but i dont know how to count them afterwards, meaning number of products for every worker since what i need are numbers, not actual sorted list.

I also tried using `COUNT(*)` instead of `product` but didnt know how to connect worker names with their count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this,

```
SELECT  worker, COUNT(*) totalProducts
FROM    tableName
WHERE   company = 2
GROUP   BY worker
```